# Generic Pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I was hoping that Haskell's compiler would understand that `f v` Is type-safe given `Unfold v f` (Although that is a tall order).

```hs
data Sequence a = FirstThen a (Sequence a) | Repeating a | UnFold b (b -> b) (b -> a)
```

Is there some way that I can encapsulate a Generic pattern for a datatype without adding extra template parameters.

*(I am aware of a solution for this specific case using lazy maps but I am after a more general solution)*

Comment: Can you give an example that causes GHC to produce an error and include the error message in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use existential quantification to get there:

```
data Sequence a = ... | forall b. UnFold b (b -> b) (b -> a)
```

I'm not sure this buys you much over the simpler solution of storing the result of unfolding directly, though:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)
data Sequence' a = ... | Explicit (Stream a)
```

In particular, if somebody hands you a `Sequence a`, you can't pattern match on the `b`'s contained within, even if you think you know what type they are.

Comment: Unfolding was just an example I came up with to see if this was possible; And if that is the case then how could you use a `forall` statement?

Comment: @Vye Okay. Does this answer meet your needs? Or is there still something that is either unclear or not a good fit for your actual use?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer, it does solve the issue but it does raise another one about how you would ever use the generic UnFold constructor as haskell doesnt (to my knowledge) have explicit generic statements.

Comment: @Vye For example, `Unfold 0 succ id` typechecks. Once you've built it, you can `toList (Unfold x f e) = e x : toList (Unfold (f x) f e)` for example.